# How can I launch pyCharm from terminal to use it with ROS?

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and wanted to use pycharm as my IDE. I'm aware that I need to modify some file "Desktop file" which I didn't know what it was.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Tools | Create Command-line Launcher" in PyCharm. This lets you choose the name of the script that will be used to start PyCharm.

Comment: Hi @yole I'm afraid I couldn't find "Create Command-line Launcher" under tools. I have the professional edition. 
P.S using Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, what can I say? The action is there. It has been available since before PyCharm 3.0. It is between "IDE Scripting Console" and "Analyze Stacktrace". If you can't find it in the menu, you can also invoke by pressing Shift twice and entering "launcher".

Comment: Wow :/ I didn't create a project that's why.